# Is there an apple silicon / M1 build of adb?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

Running all apps native improves my computer performance and battery life considerably its like magic and I am already running on Android Studio Preview Arctic Fox for some time now beta 4 but I am not getting why adb is still Intel. Emulators are also compiled for apple but why not adb ? I am searching on internet without luck too as if no one is concerned... So maybe somehow android Studio installs wrong tools for me ? I just cannot believe no one cares so should be that my install is wrong.

Comment: There's an open issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160004878

Comment: @mochadwi quite dead there actually...

Comment: Yeah, that's unfortunate, hope both Apple & Google done something for it. The good news Arctic Fox in stable channel now. We've always use Intellij IDEA for the first time for M1, now we can "confidently"(?) going back to use AS without experiencing lagging issues

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This morning I updated platform-tools (according to SDK Manager, 32.0.0) and the adb binary is now a universal binary. So now, there finally appears to be a M1 build of adb.

Comment: I am having platform tools 33.0.2 but still my CLI is not recognising `adb` command

Comment: You might have to make sure it's in your path; I had to do it manually.

Comment: I had to install it from brew, now it working fine.